# uCommerce 2.6.1 DIBS "No paytype(s)! Missing test parameter?"

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce, dibs

I've been working with uCommerce developing a webshop. I've set it up to integrate with DIBS payment services, and I got it to work properly with umbraco 4.7.2. Now, I upgraded to 4.8.0 and I get the message "No paytype(s)! Missing test parameter?" when I try to continue to the DIBS transaction page.

I'm not sure whether the error derives from the upgrade or not.

Here's my piece of code for the payment solicitation:

```
if (ProductPolicy.Checked == true)
           {

                var po = b.PurchaseOrder;

                var plpo = PipelineFactory.Create<PurchaseOrder>("Basket");

                var pm = PaymentMethod.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DIBS");

                Library.CreatePayment(pm.Id);

                plpo.Execute(po);

                po.Save();

                Library.RequestPayments();

            }
```

I've not been able to dig up any resolving solution on the internet. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Brinck10

Comment: juse the uCommerce forum at http://our.umbraco.org , they guys behind uCommerce are listening there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strike my previous answer...

According to DIBS, this happens if the DIBS account is still in test mode when you have switched off test mode in the shop, or vice versa.